# Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core

Tags: java, maven, jboss

Good day. Please point out the error. Trying to connect two brokers. Tests taken in developer studio, jboss fuse but writes to the log(below is the pom and camel-context file):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unrecognized xbean namespace mapping: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parseBeanFromExtensionElement(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:284)[org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:3.18]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:156)[org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:3.18]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler.parse(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:49)[org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1432)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1422)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:101)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:495)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-beans:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:164)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:136)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:539)[org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-context:3.2.12.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$800(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$3.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:269)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.startRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:247)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:214)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-extender:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:169)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-extender:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:175)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-core:1.2.1]
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener$2.run(ContextLoaderListener.java:716)[org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-extender:1.2.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_91]
```

Camel-context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Configures the Camel Context-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd 
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
    <!-- This creates an embedded ActiveMQ Broker -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="true"       persistent="false">
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61613" />
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>

    <!-- Lets connect the Camel ActiveMQ component to the embedded broker.
    See http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html for more information.-->

    <bean id="activemq"    class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:tcp://localhost:61613"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="websphere" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
                <property name="transportType" value="1" />
                <property name="hostName" value="***.***.***.***"/>
                <property name="port" value="port"/>
                <property name="queueManager" value="namemanager"/>
                <property name="channel" value="namechanel"/>
            </bean>
       </property>
   </bean>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="websphere:queue:TestQ"/>
            <to uri="activemq:sink-queue"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Pom file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
 <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <name>ActiveMQ embedded with Camel</name>
 <url>http://www.myorganization.org</url>

 <properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
 </properties>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
  <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
  <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
     <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>`enter code here`
  </releases>
  </repository>
  <repository>
  <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
  <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
  <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
  <snapshots>
  <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  </repository>    
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
  <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
  <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
   <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</pluginRepository>
<pluginRepository>
 <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
 <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
 <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
 <snapshots>
  <enabled>false</enabled>
 </snapshots>
 <releases>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
 </releases>
</pluginRepository>      
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>jms</groupId>
  <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
</dependency>

<!-- the ActiveMQ client with connection pooling -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- the ActiveMQ broker is optional and can be removed if connecting to a remote broker only -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
  <version>5.11.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- logging -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- testing -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
  <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <!-- allows the route to be ran via 'mvn camel:run' -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: You should place your XML configuration in alphabetical order: first the ActiveMQ elements and then the Camel elements. Take a look at the [ActiveMQ XML reference documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/xml-reference.html).

Comment: hi were you able to solve this issue?